# Setting a logback pattern in spring boot whilst using a custom contextListener

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I'm using spring boot in conjunction with logback, normally I'd specify the logging pattern I want within my application.yml.  This would allow me to change the pattern depending on the spring active profile.  However I also have a requirement to use a custom LoggerContextListener so I can inject environment variables into my logging pattern.

The only way I can see to specify a custom contextListener requires that I use a logback.xml.  This works correctly but means I can no longer switch the logging pattern within my applciation.yml.

Is there any way I can use a contextListener and still switch the pattern based on my spring active profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `logback-spring.xml` configuration file and include properties from the application environment there using the Spring extension `<springProperty>`.

See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logback-extensions

That allows you to set logback properties to values originating from your Spring environment (e.g. application.yml).